# WMI SystemSlot to PNPEntity

Tags: c#, wmi

Any way of mapping Win32_SystemSlot onto Win32_PNPEntity?

Basically, I want to get the Manufacturer of connected PCI cards, but SystemSlot's data provides nothing.

SystemSlot doesn't even give PNP Device IDs either, so I can't map it that way.

All I need is basic PCI card information, Manufacturer included!